# Is there a way to download N files from S3 as just one file?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, boto3

Current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
s3=boto3.client('s3')
list=s3.list_objects(Bucket='my_bucket_name')['Contents']
for key in list:
    s3.download_file('my_bucket_name', key['Key'], key['Key'])
```

In the specific path I have N files. This way I download them and then I have also N local files. I just want one single file.

I did:

```
data="" 

files = []
for file in glob.glob("*.json"):
    files.append(file)

for file in files:
    with open(file) as fp: 
        data += fp.read()
    data += "\n"

with open ('output.json', 'w') as fp: 
    fp.write(data)
```

Is there a way to do it faster or even using boto to stream downloaded bytes to a file?

Comment: You could download them in parallel into ObjectIOs rather then actual files. And then combine ObjectIOs into one final file.

Comment: @Marcin I dont find any reference to that :S

Comment: Sorry. Meant [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO).

Comment: @Marcin, thanks, will try!

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it will go:-)